# Error when calling Packet_Get() function in main .c file

Tags: c, embedded, lpcxpresso

I am using a library uses the function prototype of

```
void Packet_Get(void)
```

and

```
void Packet_Put(const uint8_t command,  
                const uint8_t parameter1, 
                const uint8_t parameter2, 
                const uint8_t parameter3)
```

which I can't change  and I am trying to fix the issue where when I call the function I get this error "void value not ignored as it ought to be". What would I need to do to fix the error. The function library states I need to implement a blocking function using RTOS and Semaphores, can anyone elaborate on that? Thank you in advance.

```
static void PacketGetThread(void *pData)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (Packet_Get())
        {
            HandlePackets();
        }
    }
}

void SendStartupPackets()
{
    Packet_Parameter1 = 1;
    // TODO: Send startup packets to the PC.
    return Packet_Put(CMD_STARTUP, 0, 0, 0) && HandlePacketVersion() && HandlePacketMCUNumber() && HandlePacketMCUMode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`void Packet_Put...` means it doesn't return anything, so you can't use that result together with the `&&` operator. Hence "void not ignored as it ought to be" - you get that compiler error when you attempt to use `void` as if it was a value.

Comment: So, how would I be able to call the function, I am trying to insert packets, previously it used the bool datatype but now it has been changed to void and I have tried to call the function but it's not allowing me to.

Comment: @Aaron I don't know what this function does. If you need some manner of info about if it succeeded, then maybe the API provides a different function for that? If it provides no mechanism at all, then you simply can't get any error information from it.

Comment: This is a custom function prototype in a custom library, not using any API from what I can see.

Comment: @Aaron With API (Application Programming Interface) I meant the library interface of your custom library. They could have something like a "GetLastError" flavoured function for all I know - you tell me.

Comment: I can't see any of that in the custom library.